# getting data from mysql starting with special char by using idiorm

Tags: php, mysql, idiorm

I am trying to get last 30 entries from mysql database by using idiorm. One cell contains just "/question" or "/info" stored and in my php page those rows are not displayed. I just echo the entries. In phpmyadmin they are stored, but idiorm refuses to query them.

Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: $messages= ORM::for_table('messages')->join('users', array('users.id', '=', 'messages.user_id'))->select('username')->select('time')->select('message')->order_by_asc('time')->limit(30)->find_many();

Answer (score 0):

It seems to work though. I have created some data to match your query:

```
create table users (
  id int not null auto_increment,
  username varchar(255),
  primary key(id)
);
insert into users set username = 'john';
insert into users set username = 'mike';

create table messages (
  id int not null auto_increment,
  user_id int,
  message varchar(255),
  time int,
  primary key(id),
  key(time)
);
insert into messages set user_id = 1, message = 'hello world', time = 10;
insert into messages set user_id = 2, message = '/question', time = 20;
```

Then, in PHP:

```
$messages = ORM::for_table('messages')
          ->join('users', array('users.id', '=', 'messages.user_id'))
          ->select('username')
          ->select('time')
          ->select('message')
          ->order_by_asc('time')
          ->limit(30)
          ->find_many();

foreach ($messages as $m) {
  print "[$m->username] [$m->time] [$m->message]\n";
}
```

which produced the expected output:

```
[john] [10] [hello world]
[mike] [20] [/question]
```

Perhaps there are causes unrelated to the `/` character. Perhaps the records in `message` have an incorrect foreign key (bad `user_id` value).

One way to debug this is to set

```
ORM::configure('logging', true);
```

which allows you to see the last DB query executed:

```
var_dump(ORM::get_last_query());
```

In our case, that prints:

```
SELECT `username`, `time`, `message` FROM `messages` JOIN `users` ON `users`.`id` = `messages`.`user_id` ORDER BY `time` ASC LIMIT 30
```